# What is the output if subclasss does not override to string overrided by superclass?

Tags: java, tostring, overriding

**`In which of the following case i get output "Hello World" ?`**

```
class A{

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Hello World";
}

}

public class B extends A{

public void print(){
        //replace code that displays "Hello World"
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new B().print();
    }

}
```

**I.  System.out.println(new A());**

**II. System.out.println(new B());**

**III.System.out.println(this);**

```
1. only I
2. I and III
3. I and II
4. all I,II and III
```

its `answer is 4` i.e. `all I,II and III`

*`i understood about I but why II and III is also right ?`*

**`EDIT : Also specify which section of jls provides this specification ?`**

Comment: `toString()` is overridden for all subclasses.

Comment: but here why it is printing output of to string of superclass in case of subclass instance creation

Comment: check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer a method in the class its searched in the same class if not found search in superclass and so on till you reach the `Object` class.

Whenever you do `System.out.println(object)`, its always the `toString()` method of the object will be called. If you do not implement it, the superclass `toString()` is called.

- For `System.out.println(new B());` Its `toString()` of superclass `A` is called as `B` is not overriding it.
- For `System.out.println(this);`; as `this` refers to the object of class `B`,  again `toString()` of superclass `A` is called as `B` is not overriding it.

Comment: Thanks Santosh. But do have any idea which section of jls provide reason for this.

Comment: The [specific section in JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) does not mention this explicitly. But this is the natural implication of Inheritance. [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) gives some information.

Answer (score 2):

Class B is an *extension* to class A, so B *inherits* all the methods that A has (i.e. B's toString() will also return "Hello World"). This is why when you call print() on a class B object (i.e. this and new B()), it will say "Hello World".

You will have to redefine/override the toString() function in class B again if you wanted it to return a different string.

Answer (score 0):

- System.out.println(new A());

  new object of A is created and as you are directly printing an object by default toString() method will be called.
- **System.out.println(new B());**

  new object for B is created .And now you are passing an object as parameter to println().So by default again toString() is to be called.**But since you have not defined toString() in class B.So toString() of class A will be called**
- **System.out.println(this);**

  this is same as the second case.

p.s for better understanding change the print() method in class B to toString(). Then you can see the difference.